# Wordpress header imaged not showing in IE 11 browser

Tags: php, html, wordpress, internet-explorer

I was viewing the code for the wordpress header, Go Daddy Mark I by CyberChimps, I have sent them a request. But I want to know how to include IE 11 in the Doctype html code, end if, the code includes up to 9, not sure if I use the same coding for 10 & 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
```

I could not find any other issues similar or relevant to this one.

Thank you.

Comment: Die IE Die. Die IE7. Die IE8, Die IE-all-versions DIE.. I just wanted to share the frustration about IE because I recently worked on a wordpress site that was a disaster on IE and made me work double time to tweak for this dreaded IE. Die IE. Anyway, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265532/ie-and-html5-doctype-issues as it might help you

Comment: IE10+ has stopped supporting these conditional comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

There are ways using plugins for jQuery to detect IE10+, but IE10 is much better (nowhere near perfect) at reading alot of CSS, so if you are just concerned with the appearance, I would suggest looking at alternate methods in CSS to style your content.

Comment: Here is another question asked that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: Please post a link to your WordPress instance so we can help you troubleshoot it. Internet Explorer is nowhere near as perilous as @Onimusha makes it sound. If you write clean HTML, focus on Standards, and use a Standards Doctype (which you are), you should have very few, if any, issues.