# CSS does not work with deployed application in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have developed a small web App with MVC.
I have some CSS that does work OK when in debug in visual studio i.e. on IIS Express

It looks like as below (now I cannot insert images, thanks to stackoverflow)
When I deployed this application to my local machine, some CSS does not work.

This is how the deployed application appears. I explain, all the rounded corners are gone. and the location of some DIVs is not where it is desired.
it happens in IE, Chrome is largely OK.
when I check rendred css in developer tools for IE, all the "border-radius" elements appeared underlined. and position of the DIVs can be fixed by re-adjusting margins etc (which are good to go with Chrome).
btw IE Version is 11.0.9600.16428
Windows 7 professional, IIS Version 7.5.76

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This can be several things. But I would check the following:

- Check that all css files have been deployed and contains the styling as the source.
- Check that the mark up is the same. Try opening the two sites in different tabs and check the source.
- Check your developer tools for 404 on css/js files.
- Check for javascripts errors.
- Check if the correct doctype is set.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. I have checked all this and I dont find any of the above issues with it.

Comment: And everything looks fine in chrome/firefox? Only Internet Explorer is rendering the site incorrectly?

Comment: Yes only IE. id I deploy the same site on a different server and access it through the same IE it is fine.

Comment: Yes only IE, Chrome is largely good, it has some issues like rounded corners are not working on few controls like Table, TH is fins inside the table with rounded corner. if I deploy the same site on a different server and access it through the same IE it is all fine. :? I Check it in Firefox

Comment: No 404's on Firefox, but it has the same issues as Chrome.

Comment: Without a picture it is hard to tell what is wrong. Just to make sure, did you set the doctype? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265532/ie-and-html5-doctype-issues . If what i mentioned in my post is all good then it must be a markup/doctype issue. It could also be taht Internet Explorer is set to Quirks mode.