# What's a minimally valid HTML5 document?

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I've just been reading the HTML5 author spec.
It states that the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags are *optional*.
Does that mean that you can leave them out completely and still have a valid HTML5 document?

If I'm interpreting this correctly, it means this should be completely valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>Hello!</p>
```

Is this correct?

You can check out the spec here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax

"8.1.2.4 Optional tags" is the bit out about it being OK to omit `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: Just tried it in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input It doesn't like it, reading spec now....

Comment: @Adam, if you add an empty set of `<title></title>` tags on the second line, it passes the validation.

Comment: You MUST have the `<html>` tag, as written in your link : "Documents must consist of [...] The root element, in the form of an html element." For `<head>` and `<body>`, I'll have a look.

Comment: @samsamX, no, that's inaccurate. If you read the whole doc you see later: "an HTML document always has a root html element, even if the string <html> doesn't appear anywhere in the markup.". If you omit the <html> tag in a valid way, there is an implicit root html element anyway.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong. I'm reading the whole page and it's (effectively) pretty disturbing

Comment: @samsamX, they trick you into believing it was meant to be read by humans. Even a laywer would have a hard time with the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Note that this is not an HTML5 thing. Every version of HTML (except XHTML) has specified this.

Comment: @BenLee - I disagree. While there are a few tricky bits of the HTML5 spec where you need to concentrate quite hard (the handling of namespaces springs to mind), the vast majority of it is very readable.

Comment: @Alohci, okay, I was using hyperbole. But still you have to admit it's a bit dense, even if it's understandable with careful reading. Someone even put together this: http://developers.whatwg.org/ -- an explanation of the spec designed with readability in mind, and also designed with developers in mind (anything important only to browser vendors is removed)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) element is indeed required, but as [Jukka Korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797046/whats-a-valid-html5-document#comment38285420_9797085) notes, it also must be non-empty. Furthermore, the content model of the `title` element is:

> [Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content) that is not [inter-element whitespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace).

Therefore, having just a space character in the `title` element is not considered valid HTML. You can check this in [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21doctype+html%3E%3Ctitle%3E+%3C%2Ftitle%3E).

So, an example of a minimal and valid HTML5 document is the following:

```
<!doctype html><title>a</title>
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `<meta charset="UTF-8">` here since characters may not render correctly without it.  (even if the validator doesn't complain).  Also `!DOCTYPE` may sometimes need to be uppercase see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctype

Answer (score 21):

This is the minimal HTML5-valid document:

```
<!doctype html><title> </title>
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) even the title tag may be omitted "if the element is an `<iframe>` srcdoc, or if title information is available from a higher level protocol". So the minimal HTML5-valid document is context-dependent. (I have heard it alleged that 'title information is available from a higher level protocol' covers email.)

Comment: It is no longer valid, since now HTML5 drafts require that the `title` element have nonempty content. Any character (even a space) there will do. (Until, perhaps, they change the rules again.)

Comment: According to [Validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu/) and the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) the `<title>` tag with a whitespace is regarded as empty. There has to be some non-space character inside.

Answer (score 13):

W3C HTML validator maintainer here. FYI with regard to the validator behavior, as of today, the validator now enforces the requirement in the HTML spec that the `title` element must contain at least one non-whitespace character -

http://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521doctype%2520html%3E%3Ctitle%3E%2520%2520%2520%3C%252Ftitle%3E

Comment: Is it true that the spec requires that? I see "Content model: Text that is not inter-element whitespace." But inter-element whitespace is defined as being certain forms of Text nodes. `<title></title>` has no text node children so it does not have inter-element whitespace. Text on the other hand is defined as either nothing, or text nodes. "Nothing" matches so a strict reading says that the content model is satisfied. No doubt that's not the *intent* of the definitions, but maybe there's a spec flaw there.

Answer (score 8):

While the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` start and end tags are optional, the `<title>` tags are required, except in special circumstances, so no, your sample is not (ordinarily) valid.