# In HTML5, should I skip the <html> tag?

Tags: html

I know in HTML5 it is not **neccessary** to write `<html>` tag. This is discussed in this question, regarding if it [is it necessary to write head body and html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags).

But **should** I skip it? Is it recommended to skip? The reason I ask this is I am seeing lots of HTML5 tutorials/templates on the internet that does this in their code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<head>
.....
```

Looks superfluous and completely unnecessary to me, or is it?

Comment: That particular snippet isn't superfluous. It contains a conditional comment for IE9 to insert an `ie9` class into the html element. You can't really omit a start tag if you want to declare any attributes on the element. What *is* superfluous is the start tag for head...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797046/whats-a-valid-html5-document . It has been discussed here as well. Take a look.

Comment: @BoltClock, so assuming I am not supporting IE9, should I still skip `<html>` tag? Because the tutorials/templates I am seeing are skipping them... so I am curious, is it best practice to do so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The question linked in the comments answers the question if you *can*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797046/whats-a-valid-html5-document), and that is you *can* omit in the opening `<html>` tag. However...

## You *shouldn't*.

As the answers in this question and the question linked above show, the rules around when you can or cannot omit certain tags are long and lawyer-esque.

Written code isn't just for machines its for people too. This isn't to suggest that HTML should be human-readable without a browser, that's farcical, but it should be *programmer*-readable and there is a difference.

[This is perfectly valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#optional-tags):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Hello</title>
<p>Welcome to this example.</p>
```

However, without consulting the spec I am not immediately sure where each element will be in the computed DOM, for the curious its equivalent to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>Hello</title>
</head><body><p>Welcome to this example.</p></body></html>
```

However, if time is at a premium (and programmer time is almost always more expensive than computing time nowadays) then knowing quite clearly what a document is doing is vital.

---

No doubt someone will ask, what about when space or transmission speed is at a premium. In those cases thorough profiling to determine the exact bottleneck is important, and on the fly compression, good caching of HTML, or even automated removal of elements using a library will all be vastly superior options to removing tags in source code that is to be written and interpreted by people.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the tutorials/templates author is trying to save a few bytes... :p

Comment: That, or trying to be clever.

Answer (score 0):

`<html>` is required for a valid HTML document only if the tag is preceded by a comment.

> An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.

See the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html) for details.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of XHTML instead?

Comment: Pretty sure the linked document says HTML

Comment: The correct link is [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#optional-tags) (or [here](http://drafts.htmlwg.org/html/master/syntax.html#optional-tags) for the less bandwidth-inclined) and it states pretty clearly that the tags can be omitted, and furthermore that omitting the tags doesn't mean the element isn't present, particularly for the html element.

Comment: That looks better. (Well, absent the hashtag anyway.)