# HTML5 Starter Page

Tags: html

Is this the basic html5 bolier code?

```
<!doctype html>
```

` //do I still need this?
                my title

```
<body>
    //my body 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797085/8516343) answer shows the minimum required valid HTML5 document.

So yes you do need a `<title> </title>` after your `<!doctype html>` as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This, for me is

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `title` tag is necessary. This is the minimal valid `html5` document you can use.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>I'm the shortest valid HTML5</title>
```