# Set custom initial page in blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

Is it possible to set the initial page in blogdown? Instead of the default one that shows the posts I would like to have a custom one. I want to have my own index.html (the root one).

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [Lithium - A simple responsive Hugo theme](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium), one possible way to do this is the following.

1] Copy `layouts/_default/list.html` to a new layout file named `layouts/_default/home.html`

2] Edit `layouts/_default/home.html` so it contains this:

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

<main class="content" role="main">

<h1>
My heading
</h1>

<p>
My paragraph
</p>

</main>

{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

Your home page will now contain "My heading" and "My paragraph," along with the Lithium header and footer. If you do not want to use the Lithium header and/or footer, remove those partial calls from home.html.[*] There's a lot more that you can do with Hugo layout files, which you can learn about in my Hugo tutorial in the section [15. Explore the layouts directory](https://www.ii.com/themeless-gitless-intro-hugo/#_explore_the_layouts_directory) and at gohugo.io's [Category: templates](https://gohugo.io/categories/templates/).

I hope this is enough to get you started with Hugo layout files.

[*] If you remove the header partial, you need to put something like `<!doctype html><title>a</title>` at the top. More about this is in [What's a valid HTML5 document? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797046/whats-a-valid-html5-document)