# HTML 5 Validation Service

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation, standards-compliance

I am trying to check HTML 5 files for validity and have found the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu).
However I have found that this validator accepts grossly wrong HTML documents like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have removed the opening html tag, and the opening body tag and the validator reports:

> The document validates according to the specified schema(s).

I do not assume, that this document is anyhow compliant to the HTML 5 or any other HTML standard. Obviously the validator is not very strict, when it comes to nesting of elements or opening/closing tags.

Is there a more strict validator out there, which reports every tiny deviation from standard HTML?

Comment: You can ask that W3C validator to check against e.g. HTML 4.01 Strict, which does show errors. Just pick the appropriate doctype on https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options.

Comment: Thanks, True That. That does the trick for html 4. I have changed the title - I need to check html5 files.

Comment: I don't think that _is_ "grossly wrong" as HTML5, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9797046/3001761

Answer (score 1):

> I do not assume, that this document is anyhow compliant to the html5 or any other html standard.

But you are assuming that it isn't compliant. You could check by *reading* the standard.

See, for example, [the html element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> Tag omission in text/html:
> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
> An html element's end tag can be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

---

> Is there a more strict validator out there, which reports every tiny deviation from standard html?

While tool recommendations are off-topic for this site, there are no deviations from standard html in the code you've presented.

The Nu validator is very good at what it does.