# Doctype messing with CSS font styling?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser, compatibility

I’m guessing I need a doctype because the following font styling only appears how I want it in Safari and Chrome.  So every time I add the HTML5 doctype, writing in my custom font dissapears.  I’m an amateur coder so please bare with the code, I taught myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    #yolk {
        background-image: url(Yolk.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        padding-top:250px;
    }
    body {
        background-color:#000000;
    }
    #lol {
        background-image: url(lol.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: my_font;
        src: url('http://myurl.com/lolfont.eot');
        src: url('lolfont.eot'), url('lolfont.ttf') format('opentype');
    }
    p {
        font-family: my_font; 
        color: de0000;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 10%;
        text-indent: 350px;

    }
    </style>
    <title>yolk</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="yolk"></div>
    <center>
    <embed allowScriptAccess="never" src="http://swing.awardspace.com/newcoun… width=320  height=110 wmode=transparent menu=false></embed>
    </center>
    <p>test</p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="lol"><div id="lol"></div></a>
    </font>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I'm guessing I need a doctype because the following font styling only appears how I want it in Safari and Chrome. So every time I add the HTML5 doctype, writing in my custom font dissapears*" - So, when you add the doctype, the font styles disappear. And that's why you need a doctype? Wait, what?

Answer (score 1):

Always [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) first.  When trying to do anything with invalid markup, you just waste your and other people’s time.  Then, you can [validate your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

The mistakes I discovered:

- `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` should be [`<!DOCTYPE html>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE) as you are using [XML serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html), which is case sensitive.  The thing immediately after `<!DOCTYPE` is the name of the document’s root element.  See also [Uppercase or lowercase doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020961/2157640) on SO.
- `color: de0000;` should be `color: #de0000;`.
- The `body` element must be closed. place `</body>` right before `</html>`.
- Remove the `</font>` tag – no opening tag is present.  Also the [`font` element is obsolete](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font).
- Replace the [`center` element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center) with `div` having `style="text-align: center"`. It is obsolete.
- Fix `<embed allowScriptAccess="never" src="http://swing.awardspace.com/newcoun… width=320  height=110 wmode=transparent menu=false></embed>`. All attributes in XML serialization of HTML5 must have quotes around their values. The contents of `src` attribute is clearly truncated, with final quote missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your CSS code, it can be the color which you didn't start with `#`. I had a similar problem because I've written `font-size: 12;` instead of `font-size: 12px;`.

By the way I think this

```
url('lolfont.ttf') format('opentype');
```

should be rather

```
url('lolfont.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Answer (score -1):

First check if you have the correct url for your fonts, for example this URL that you included is not correct, it doesn't refer to any font.

```
src: url('http://myurl.com/lolfont.eot'); //???
```

as indicated in w3School:

> Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support fonts of type .ttf (True Type Fonts) and .otf (OpenType Fonts).Internet Explorer 9+ supports the new @font-face rule, but it only supports fonts of type .eot (Embedded OpenType).Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the new @font-face rule.

So there shouldn't be any problem with safari or chrome...

The correct format for @font-face according to [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp) is:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
@font-face
{
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
  url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9+ */
}

div
{
   font-family:myFirstFont;
}
</style>
```

For seeing where is your problem a better idea is to start from a simple code, (something like [w3School example](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-face_rule)) Then integrate it with your code...

and by the way, if you check the DOCTYPE in the example is as follows: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
However, when you change it to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` it still works...

Comment: Thanks but I tried your suggestions and it still dosent work.

Comment: -1 For linking to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) as to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/). This is seriously misleading as W3Schools have nothing to do with W3C. Also W3Schools is controversial because of inaccurate information. See [W3Fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/).