# DOCTYPE gives 'unexpected' error when XmlPullParser is used

Tags: java, android

Below is the error that logcat springs up. It is unable to parse the <!DOCTYPE...> at the start of any xml document. I tried my program with a page that doesn't have the DOCTYPE tag and it worked successfully. I have used setFeature to enable 'FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL', but it doesn't solve the problem.

The Error:
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected <! (position:START_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in 
java.io.InputStreamReader@424355f0)

Excerpt of my code:

URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww");

```
                XmlPullParserFactory parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                parser.setNamespaceAware(true);
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,true); 
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL,true); 
                XmlPullParser xpp = parser.newPullParser();

                InputStream ip=url.openConnection().getInputStream();

                xpp.setInput(ip, HTTP.UTF_8);
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


                int eventType=xpp.getEventType();

                if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){

                while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT ){

                    if(eventType!=XmlPullParser.DOCDECL){
                        eventType=xpp.nextToken();
                    }
                    else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){    
                        if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){


                        bundle.putString("message", xpp.nextText());
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg); 
                            eventType=xpp.nextToken();   
                            }
                            }

                  }
                      }
```

Comment: It's probably unrelated, but there's a similar looking [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182605): Reuse of XmlPullParser raises "Unexpected token" on DOCTYPE declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar problem. Looks like XmlPullParser doesn't accept the lower case `<!doctype html>`, instead, it expects the upper-cased version `<!DOCTYPE html>`. (Related: [Uppercase or lowercase doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctype)).

This can be found at **org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.java**:

```
/**
 * Returns the type of the next token.
 */
private int peekType(boolean inDeclaration) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
```

Beginning at line 1003:

```
case '!':
                    switch (buffer[position + 2]) {
                        case 'D':
                            return DOCDECL; // <!D
                        case '[':
                            return CDSECT; // <![
                        case '-':
                            return COMMENT; // <!-
                        case 'E':
                            switch (buffer[position + 3]) {
                                case 'L':
                                    return ELEMENTDECL; // <!EL
                                case 'N':
                                    return ENTITYDECL; // <!EN
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'A':
                            return ATTLISTDECL;  // <!A
                        case 'N':
                            return NOTATIONDECL; // <!N
                    }
                    throw new XmlPullParserException("Unexpected <!", this, null);
```

The workaround I used was to search for that specific line and upper case it.

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing HTML as if it were XML - it's not.

You'll either need to use a library which converts HTML to XML, or a library which gives you access to whichever bits of the HTML DOM you're interested in, or fetch XML instead of HTML.

(You should also check the terms of service before scraping a web site...)

Comment: But the XmlPullParser documentation on developer.android.com clearly mentions DOCTYPE and how to tackle it. I will look for a library anyhow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DOCTYPE comes after the XML preprocessor instruction.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ...>
```

This might be a bit counter-intuitive.