# AngularJS: "Hello Word" not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've had a look at similar answers but haven't seen an answer to this.

My directory structure is simply:

```
Test
|---index.html
|---bootstrap.min.css
|---angular.min.js
|---app.js
```

My code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <p>I am {{4 + 6}}</p>
    <p>{{"Hello" + " you"}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Sadly, running this in the browser (file:///Users/Will/Projects/angular/demo/index.html), it doesn't work. Is this because it's local?

Comment: Post `app.js` code please :-)

Comment: possibly some syntax error in app.js ?

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors. Also, the doctype should probably be `<!DOCTYPE html>` though I'm not sure if it matters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctype

Comment: app.js only has one line: var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that the following works when loaded directly from the filesystem (and not a webserver):

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

<p>I am {{4 + 6}}</p>
<p>{{"Hello" + " you"}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I have changed "ng-app='store'" to "ng-app", so that angular is not trying to load the 'store' module.

This shows that angular, on its own, is doing its thing correctly. So the issue is somewhere within the store module. As suggested in the comments, check your browser console for error messages, and troubleshoot those.