# Trying to insert into database using id from link and prepared statement

Tags: php, html, sql, prepared-statement

I currently have the following code. What I'm trying to do is fetch the `oppdrID=x` from the link and put the query into the row with the same `oppdrID`. I can't get it to work because something is not working. What am I dong wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilsett.php" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Endre oppdrag // Prosjekt - PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include "funksjoner.inc.php";
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['brukernavn'])) {

echo "<div id='header'>";

echo navigasjon();

echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='innhold'>";

$startTid = mysqli_real_escape_string(kobleTil(),  htmlspecialchars($_POST['startTid']));
$slutTid = mysqli_real_escape_string(kobleTil(),  htmlspecialchars($_POST['slutTid']));
$merknad = mysqli_real_escape_string(kobleTil(), htmlspecialchars($_POST['merknad']));
$antTimer = mysqli_real_escape_string(kobleTil(), htmlspecialchars($_POST['antTimer']));

if ($startTid == '' || $slutTid == '' || $merknad == '' || $antTimer == '')  {

$error = "Vennligst fyll inn alle dataene!";

}

$db = kobleTil();
if (isset($_GET['oppdrID']) && is_numeric($_GET['oppdrID']) &&   $_GET['oppdrID'] > 0) {

$id = $_GET['oppdrID'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO timeregistrering WHERE oppdrID = ? (startTid, sluttTid,  merknad, timer) values ('$startTid', '$slutTid', '$merknad', '$antTimer');
";

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {

$stmt->bind_param("i", $id, $startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);
$stmt->execute();

if ($db->query($sql)) {

    echo "<p><b>Tabellen ble opprettet!</b></p>";
    echo "<b>Spørringen som ble kjørt:</b><pre>$sql</pre>";

    } else {

    echo "<p>Noe gikk galt :(</p>" . $error;
        }
    }
    }
}

echo "</div>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using the XML serialization of HTML5 (XHTML5), then the DOCTYPE should be capitalized like such: `<!DOCTYPE html>` (for more information, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109157) SO answer) - Just thought it should be noted to cover all bases.

Comment: oh .. thanks for the headsup @Idempotence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your prepared statement is wrong, try this instead:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO timeregistrering(startTid, sluttTid,  merknad, timer) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";`

`$stmt->bind_param($startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);`

I removed the where clause because you can't use `where` on an `insert` unless it is `where not exists`

Comment: Changed the values to ?s, but there is still not a lot happening.

Comment: Are you getting an error at all? Or is there any data being inserted into the _timeregistrering_ table?

Comment: I think you can also remove

Comment: Try removing this if statement: `if ($db->query($sql)) {`. You are executing the SQL inside: `$stmt->execute();`

Try adding this line after the `execute()`: `printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);`

Comment: forgot the " after the values and NOW im getting the error ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'i' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\kjoerx.php on line 44

Comment: Make sure you also updated the bind_param statement to be: `$stmt->bind_param($startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);`

Comment: `$stmt->prepare($sql) 
$stmt->bind_param($startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);
$stmt->execute();
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->$error);` error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\kjoerx.php on line 4

Comment: I think you are missing a semi-colon after your prepare:

Comment: `$stmt->prepare($sql);` `stmt->bind_param($startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);` `$stmt->execute(); printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->$error);`

Comment: I was ... fix it, but still no errors nor data in the database. the database has the columns timeID-oppdrID-startTid-sluttTid-merknad-time where timeID is increment and oppdrID is a foreign key

Comment: Ahh in that case you do need to pass through the foreign key: 

`$sql = "INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid,  merknad, timer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";` 

AND 

`$stmt->bind_param($id, $startTid, $slutTid, $merknad, $antTimer);` 

If that doesn't work you might want to try and re-create this insert statement on the command line using mysql. E.g: `INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid,  merknad, timer) values (1,1,1,1,1)` and see if you get an error.

Comment: okey, I tried to enter the statement directly into the database and get the error #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1' for column 'startTid' at row 1.

Comment: the $startTid and slutTid are datetime-local, merknad is a textarea and antTimer is text

Comment: Did it work on the page now that it is inserting the foreign key? Yeah try inserting it with the mysql client with a date for startTid, you can use the mysql `NOW()` function. `INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid, merknad, timer) values (NOW(),1,1,'test','test timer')`

Comment: `INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid, merknad, timer) values (1,NOW(),NOW(),'test','2')` worked putting in into the client

Comment: The next thing I would check then is the actual values you are trying to insert. On your php page I would `echo` them out( `echo 'id is: '.$id.'<br>';` etc), then try to use those values on your insert statement: `INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid, merknad, timer) values (value of $id,'value of $startTid','value of $sluttTid','value of $merknad','value of $antTimer')`. That should give you some type of error. If that works there must still be a PHP error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\kjoerx.php on line 53 `echo 'id is: '.$id.'<br>';`

Comment: the rest prints out

Comment: hm .. seems like ive done a tiny mistake here ...the run-script doesnt have the id in the link ... the page it is sent from does ... fixed this my fetching the id from the link on the formpage, sending it via the form and to this page. `<input type='text' name='id' value='$id' id='skjemaLeggInn'>` - > `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string(kobleTil(), htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));` still getting Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\kjoerx.php on line 41 and Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\prosjekt\kjoerx.php on line 41 tho

Comment: It sounds like you aren't connecting to the database. This page has a pretty good example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php You need to connect to your database and then use that variable to run the prepare function, so like: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

Comment: `$db = kobleTil();` connects the page to the database. funksjoner.inc.php = `function kobleTil() {
 
$vert = "localhost";
$databasenavn = "prosjektphp";
$bruker = "prosjektphp";
$passord = "";
$db = new mysqli($vert, $bruker, $passord, $databasenavn);
return $db;
}`

Comment: got it working! finale code is `$sql = "INSERT INTO timeregistrering(oppdrID, startTid, sluttTid, merknad, timer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
  $stmt->prepare($sql); 
  $stmt->bind_param('issss', $id, $startTid, $sluttTid, $merknad, $antTimer);
  $stmt->execute(); 

echo 'id is: '.$id.'<br>';
echo 'startTid is: '.$startTid.'<br>';
echo 'sluttTid is: '.$sluttTid.'<br>';
echo 'merknad is: '.$merknad.'<br>';
echo 'antTimer is: '.$antTimer.'<br>';`

Comment: Can you accept the answer since everything is working now? :-)