# Why "<!DOCTYPE>" and not "<!doctype>"?

Tags: html

Bit of an academia question—from everything I read, html is case insensitive (with the acceptation to `#iDs` and `.classNames`).

When I run the following snippet through an html validator I get no errors:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This being the case, why is it commonly declared `<!DOCTYPE html>` and not `<!doctype html>`?

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020961/5267751)

Comment: I always use `<!doctype html>` -- it's consistent with my other HTML tags that way. But you can use `<!DoCtYpE hTmL>` if you like. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input @T.J.Crowder. It just seemed strange to me given that everything else was lower-case—made my eyes twitch.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just to be pedantic, 1) `<!DOCTYTPE html>` is not a tag. 2) In an XHTML environment you will need to write lowercase `html`. The `doctype` will still be case insensitive though.

Comment: @MrLister: 1. I know, the word "other" shouldn't have slipped into that sentence. 2. XHTML is the spawn of the devil. I cross the street and cross myself whenever I see it. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't diss XHTML like that; it's really not that bad. Just different. You can do things with XHTML that you can't do with HTML. Anyway, I just found that I was wrong and that DOCTYPE should be written in all uppercase in XHTML. Otherwise you get a syntax error in the browser. (Now maybe you may not care about this, but it goes a long way toward explaining why so many people do write DOCTYPE in uppercase!)

Comment: It used to be case-sensitive, but is no longer case-sensitive in HTML5. The [HTML5 Reference](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) suggests that you use the all-caps version.

Comment: @MrLister: Sorry, XHTML may have served a purpose in 2002 or 2003. It certainly doesn't in 2018. **;-)** Interesting about XHTML breaking if you write the `html` in lower case. Classic. :-) *(This is joke trolling, not real trolling.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a convention that we do uppercase. The [spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype) that it's case-insensitive.

> In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, case-insensitively.