# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from adding extra doctype entry

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I read an html file and load it with bs4, I get an extra doctype entry.  How can I prevent it?

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
<body>
<p>
text body
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the file is processed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.urlopen(file_name).read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

The resulting HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
<body>
<p>
text body
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is not with BS as I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Running this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


file_name = 'file:///C:/Users/tang/MathScripts/t.html'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(file_name).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">

<html>
<body>
<p>
text body
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I spent some time on this issue and learned that the issue repros if "!DOCTYPE" is written with small cases, "!doctype".  I am not so sure if this is by design or not.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doctype string is case insensitive in HTML spec, but case sensitive in XML spec.

It is explained very well in this [post: "Uppercase or lowercase doctype?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctype#:%7E:text=In%20both%20cases%20it%20is%20declared%20as%20the,software%20is%20not%20in%20compliance%20with%20the%20standards.).

Based on this information, I think BeautifulSoup is not handling html doctype string properly.

I changed my code as below and it works fine now.

```
page = urllib.urlopen(file_name).read()
# case insensitive replace to consider all case permutations
page = re.sub('<!doctype', '<!DOCTYPE', page, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

I am not so sure if the html specification has been updated or not.

Please post comment if you have more information to share.

Answer (score 0):

Found one more solution.

I replaced 'html.parser' with 'html5lib' and it works fine.

```
page = urllib.urlopen(file_name).read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
```